# Compiling Zxing library to .a file and include in project

Tags: iphone, zxing

Is it possible to compile Zxing iphone library to .a extension and add them to project?  Basically I am looking at changing the CPP and moving them inside my project folder rather than placing them outside the folder.

Thanks in advance for helping me out on this.

Comment: have u found the soln. i am having same isuue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the instructions are in the README for the zxing google code: http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/iphone/README